# How to pass arguments to another .py

Tags: python, function, memory-management, memory-leaks, subprocess

I'm newbie with python programming and I'm facing an issue with Windows Memory, so I want to understand if the way I'm calling the other "subprogram" ic causing this problem.
Basically I've done a main program from which I call the other .py (called second_py.py) like this:

```
from second_py import second_py

variable_1, variable_2 = second_py(input_1, input_2, input_3)
```

the second_py is ended with a `return` and the input_1/2/3 can be different from where this second_py.py is executed in the main program.

is this way correct?
I've seen that it is also possible to use the `subprocess.call` but honestly it is not clear to me how to pass to it the inputs.

Comment: I believe you need to modify the name of the function so that it's not called like the name of the file

Comment: So what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

> **second_py.py**

```
def my_function(a,b,c):
    print ("I am a function from 'second_py' file!")
    return(a+b+c, a*b*c)
```

> **first_py.py**

```
from second_py import my_function

#Call the second_py function here
v1,v2=my_function(3,5,4)

print(v1,v2)
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: yes this is how I've done....but my question is: when doing so, once the second.py has done his job, does python "release" the occupied memory?

Comment: This is the job of the garbage collector. It uses references count: if an object’s reference count is 0, the memory for the object is deallocated. But I don't see why this should be any of your concerns